# Detect Mobile Device Shake (NextJS)

Tags: next.js

I'm currently using Next 13 on my website and I would like to implement something that will increment the counter for every shake detected on your mobile device. I have tried using `window.DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission()` to gain access to the `window.addEventListener('devicemotion', (event) => {console.log(event);})` but NextJS returned `Property 'requestPermission' does not exist`. Any ideas or tips on how to implement this feature?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you sould use `SSL Certificate` in your app to have this feature

[here](https://www.makeuseof.com/create-react-app-ssl-https/) the official documentation